# PHP - HTML Purifier - hello w<o>rld/world tutorial striptags

Tags: php, validation, user-input, sanitization

I am just looking into using HTML Purifier to ensure that a user-inputed string (that represents the name of a person) is sanitized.

I do not want to allow any html tags, script, markup etc - I just want the alpha, numeric and normal punctuation characters.

The sheer number of options available for HTML Purifier is daunting and, as far as i can see, the docs do not seem to have a beggining/middle or end

see: http://htmlpurifier.org/docs

**Is there a simple hello world tutorial online for HTML Purifier that shows how to sanitize a string removing all the bad stuff out of it.**

I am also considering just using strip tags:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

or PHP's in built data sanitizing

- http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

Comment: I'd say go for the simple `strip_tags()` for a trivial task like this :) Pros: Easy to implement, easy to understand, easy to replace (whenever the requirements change). Cons: ?

Comment: I second what jensgram says. This is a task for `strip_tags()` and `htmlentities()` - should be enough to thwart any attack.

Comment: yes - i'd love to use strip tags but i read that "striptags() is fundamentally flawed and should not be used." - http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison#striptags - yet i am not sure how up-to-date that is or how relevant it is to its 'blanket usage' of removing all tags

Comment: @JW "Removes foreign tags: Buggy" worries me a little. But "well-formed", "nesting", and "attributes" are safe to ignore in your case.

Comment: HTML Purifier is a wonderful tool **for HTML**. Using it on a non-HTML text-string is not great. It'll do some things for you, but it's not really what you want.

Comment: No one answered the real question: Is there a simple hello world tutorial online for HTML Purifier that shows how to sanitize a string removing all the bad stuff out of it. :(

Comment: Ha ha! Yes. This question has been open for a while. I guess the answer is no. Add it as an answer and you might win points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been using HTMLPurifier for sanitizing the output of a rich text editor, and ended up with:

```
include_once('htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php');

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core', 'Encoding', 'UTF-8');
$config->set('HTML', 'Doctype', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional');

if (defined('PURIFIER_CACHE')) {
    $config->set('Cache', 'SerializerPath', PURIFIER_CACHE);
} else {
    # Disable the cache entirely
    $config->set('Cache', 'DefinitionImpl', null);
}

# Help out the Purifier a bit, until it develops this functionality
while (($cleaner = preg_replace('!<(em|strong)>(\s*)</\1>!', '$2', $input)) != $input) {
    $input = $cleaner;
}

$filter = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$output = $filter->purify($input);
```

The main points of interest:

1. Include the autoloader.
2. Create an instance of `HTMLPurifier_Config` as `$config`.
3. Set configuration settings as needed, with `$config->set()`.
4. Create an instance of `HTMLPurifier`, passing `$config` to it.
5. Use `$filter->purify()` on your input.

However, it's entirely overkill for something that doesn't need to allow any HTML in the output.

Comment: It may be overkill, but it answers the question. So, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should do input validation based on the content - for example rather use some regexp for name

```
'/([A-Z][a-z]+[ ]?)+/' //ascii only, but not problematic to extend
```

this validation should do the job well. And then escape the output when printing it on page, with preferred [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use someting like htmlspecialchars() to preserve the characters the user typed in without the browser interpreting.

Answer (score 0):

I've always thought Codeigniter's xss cleaning class was quite good, but more recently I've turned to Kohana.

Have a look at their xss_clean method

http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/c443c44922ef13421f4a3af5b414e19091bbdce9/classes/kohana/security.php

Answer (score 0):

HTMLpurifier in action. You can opt to write `<?php echo "HELLO";?>` in `fname` and `WORLD` in `lname` and check the output.

```html
<?php
include( 'htmlpurifier/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php');
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="first name"><br>
<input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="last name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
        
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    
    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    $fname = $purifier->purify($fname);
    
    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    $lname = $purifier->purify($lname);

    echo "First name is: ".$fname."<br>";
    echo "Last name is: ".$lname;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to remove all non-alphanumeric characters from a string i think is to use RegEx.Replace() as follows:

Regex.Replace(stringToCleanUp, "[\W]", "");

While \w (lowercase) matches any ‘word’ character, equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]
\W matches any ‘non-word’ character, ie. anything NOT matched by \w.
The code above will use \W (uppercase) and replace the findings with nothing.

As an alternative if you don’t want to allow the underscore you can use [^a-zA-Z0-9], like this:

Regex.Replace(stringToCleanUp, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");

Comment: Thanks for these Mikulas Dite and omadmedia. I will probably add some regi into the mix. However i still would like to know if there is a hello world tutorial for HTML Purifier. I guess someone would have pointed to one by now if there was.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to evade code injection attacks, just scape the data and store and print it like the user entered.

For example: If you want to avoid SQL Injection problems in MySQL, use the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function or similar to sanitize the SQL sentence. *

Another example: Writing data to a HTML document, parse the data with `html_entities()`, so the data will appears like enter by the user.

- Check: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: thanks. but no, it not quite what i wanted. the main thing i am looking for is to strip all markup and scripts from user input leaving alpha, numeric and grammatical characters. allow '<' , disallow '<a></a>'. allow '>' disallow '<?php ... ?>' etc

Answer (score -1):

For simplicity, you can either use `strip_tags()`, or replace occurrences of <, >, and & with `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;`, respectively. This definitely isn't the best solution, but the quickest.

Answer (score -2):

i usually clean all user input before sending to my database with the following

```
mysql_reql_escape_string( htmlentities( strip_tags($str) ));
```

Comment: Why? `mysql_real_escape_string()` makes sense, and if you have GPC magic quotes enabled you may need to do `striptags()`, but why the `htmlentities()`?

Comment: so that when you show the value from the db in a browser its valid html

Comment: I'd do that when I'm outputting it, not when saving it. That way the database stores real data. Makes sense to me, anyway. *shrug*

Comment: personal preference, not really worth a -1 IMO

Answer (score -2):

Found this a week ago...  LOVE it.

"A simple PHP HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+, supports invalid HTML, and provides a very easy way to handle HTML elements."
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
// Example
$html = str_get_html("<div>foo <b>bar</b></div>");
$e = $html->find("div", 0);

echo $e->tag; // Returns: " div"
echo $e->outertext; // Returns: " <div>foo <b>bar</b></div>"
echo $e->innertext; // Returns: " foo <b>bar</b>"
echo $e->plaintext; // Returns: " foo bar"
```

You can also loop through and remove individual tags, etc.  The docs and examples are pretty good... I found it easy to use in quite a few places. :-)

Comment: This seems like it might fit the bill. I hadn't considered using a DOM parser for this - but it makes sense. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Pedantic Note: this has nothing to do with security or sanitization.  SimpleHTMLDom is just for working the elements in an object-oriented manner.  -1