# No HTML at all with HTML Purifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

If I want to remove all the HTML code of my text, but still having an understandable text, which method should I use?

Should I use HTML Purifier with `$Configuracion->set('HTML.Allowed', '');` or another way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - HTML Purifier - hello w<o>rld/world tutorial striptags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677578/php-html-purifier-hello-world-world-tutorial-striptags)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTML Purifier has a notable bug for the "convert HTML to plain text" case, where block-level elements may lose the spaces between them when all the tags are removed. HTML Purifier wasn't designed for this use case.

Answer (score 5):

PHP's built-in [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) generally works well for this.

Comment: Note that this will let you keep certain useful tags, too: `echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');`

Comment: Thank you ceejayoz, but I wanted to learn about HTML Purifier (http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Comment: Don't say "or another way" then?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I meant "another way with HtmlPurifier, ie, another way instead of using $Configuracion->set('HTML.Allowed', '');
Thank you anyway.

Comment: Anyway ceejayoz: Could I use strip_tags() in a completely secure way? I mean, I was considering about using HtmlPurifier to avoid XSS attacks or messy Html or whatever incorrect code. Is strip_tags() "perfect" for that? Thank you again.

Answer (score -2):

The default behavior of HTML Purifier is to remove all tags.