# Extend htmlpurifier to personal configuration

Tags: php, oop, htmlpurifier

Is it possible to take the below original code, and wrap it in a new class so I may simply create `$filter = new myPurifier();` and then use `$output = $filter->purify($input);`?  At the bottom of this post, you will see my failed attempt to do so. Thanks

original code:

```
include_once('htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php');

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core', 'Encoding', 'UTF-8');
$config->set('HTML', 'Doctype', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional');

if (defined('PURIFIER_CACHE')) {
    $config->set('Cache', 'SerializerPath', PURIFIER_CACHE);
} else {
    # Disable the cache entirely
    $config->set('Cache', 'DefinitionImpl', null);
}

# Help out the Purifier a bit, until it develops this functionality
while (($cleaner = preg_replace('!<(em|strong)>(\s*)</\1>!', '$2', $input)) != $input) {
    $input = $cleaner;
}

$filter = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$output = $filter->purify($input);
```

reference: Above code found at [PHP - HTML Purifier - hello w<o>rld/world tutorial striptags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677578/php-html-purifier-hello-world-world-tutorial-striptags)

My attempt to do so which doesn't work:

```
class myhtmlpurifier extends HTMLPurifier
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once VS_APPLICATION_BASE.DS.'classes_3rd/htmlpurifier-4.4.0/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
        $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
        $config->set('Core', 'Encoding', 'UTF-8');
        $config->set('HTML', 'Doctype', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional');
        if (defined('PURIFIER_CACHE')) {
            $config->set('Cache', 'SerializerPath', PURIFIER_CACHE);
        } else {
            # Disable the cache entirely
            $config->set('Cache', 'DefinitionImpl', null);
        }

        # Help out the Purifier a bit, until it develops this functionality
        while (($cleaner = preg_replace('!<(em|strong)>(\s*)</\1>!', '$2', $input)) != $input) {
            $input = $cleaner;
        }
        $this = parent::__construct($config);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a two things wrong with your attempt:

- Attempting to include the class you're inheriting from from the constructor
- Referencing an undefined `$input` variable to help clean things up

In order to implement what you want, you should move the require outside, and move the `while` loop into an overloaded version of the `purify` method.