# how to protect from XSS in WYSIWYG

Tags: xss, htmlpurifier

i store user input from `WYSIWYG` to `SQL` database, 
I need to protect from `XSS` attack and found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1996141/3836908)

Since am using `WYSIWYG` and found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7829102/3836908)

My problem is which is best way to protect from `XSS` do i need to use `HTML Purifier`

or i can use this simple method;

```
echo htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: you can use HTML Purifier

Answer (score 1):

The best method depends on your use-case. If you use `htmlspecialchars()`, then if your user enters **bold text** in the WYSIWYG, it will show up on your page either as `<b>bold text</b>` or `<strong>bold text</strong>`. That's probably not what you want.

If you actually want to output the formatted text from your WYSIWYG, you need to sanitise the HTML input. [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs) is one good option for that, and quite easy to set up.

In short: It depends on if you actually want to output formatted text or not. *If you don't*, `htmlspecialchars()` is easier and consumes less resources. Since you're letting users use a WYSIWYG, I assume you do, though, and in that case `htmlspecialchars()` will ruin what you're even trying to achieve.